# how to minify javascript generated by ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, minify

I knew few javascript file compressors/minifiers. Lately I am using pagesped and Yslow which sugegsted that all java script should be minified. Hence we minified all the inline script too. Still we are receiving minify java script suggestion. 
After verification I found that the java script generated in by ASP.NET for its controls and other stuff. I am wondering how to minify the script [that willbe] generated by ASP.NET. We cannot do this pre-build as far as I know. Any setting in IIS which specifies ASP.NET to generate minified js?

I have turned the debug mode off. Still it is not getting minified

Please help me with this....

A Part of the script being generated for my website is:

```
function WebForm_PostBackOptions(eventTarget, eventArgument, validation, validationGroup, actionUrl, trackFocus, clientSubmit) {
    this.eventTarget = eventTarget;
    this.eventArgument = eventArgument;
    this.validation = validation;
    this.validationGroup = validationGroup;
    this.actionUrl = actionUrl;
    this.trackFocus = trackFocus;
    this.clientSubmit = clientSubmit;
}
function WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(options) {
    var validationResult = true;
    if (options.validation) {
        if (typeof(Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
            validationResult = Page_ClientValidate(options.validationGroup);
        }
    }
    if (validationResult) {
        if ((typeof(options.actionUrl) != "undefined") && (options.actionUrl != null) && (options.actionUrl.length > 0)) {
            theForm.action = options.actionUrl;
        }
        if (options.trackFocus) {
            var lastFocus = theForm.elements["__LASTFOCUS"];
            if ((typeof(lastFocus) != "undefined") && (lastFocus != null)) {
                if (typeof(document.activeElement) == "undefined") {
                    lastFocus.value = options.eventTarget;
                }
                else {
                    var active = document.activeElement;
                    if ((typeof(active) != "undefined") && (active != null)) {
                        if ((typeof(active.id) != "undefined") && (active.id != null) && (active.id.length > 0)) {
                            lastFocus.value = active.id;
                        }
                        else if (typeof(active.name) != "undefined") {
                            lastFocus.value = active.name;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (options.clientSubmit) {
        __doPostBack(options.eventTarget, options.eventArgument);
    }
}
```

Comment: How many bytes are you trying to save? Are we talking Kilobytes?

Comment: System.Web.Extensions.dll for Microsoft Ajax serve up a minified version of the .js depending on the debug compilation flag... WebForms.js and WebUIValidation.js requests from .axd to System.Web.dll however does not seem to adhere to this.... in .NET 3.5 at least :(

Comment: .Thanks for the response guys ..I am trying to save ,if not 1, at least 2 kilo bytes. And my pagespeed says you can reduce that too.. But I am not sure how to do that